# What does Zabbix message "Free disk space is less than XX% on volume Shared memory" mean?

Tags: memory-usage, zabbix

I use Zabbix to monitor my environment. The Zabbix server warns me with the following message:

"Free disk space is less than 20% on volume Shared memory"

Can someone explain "volume Shared memory" in this context?

How should I address this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/dev/shm is a temporary filesystem mounted usually under /run/shm for IPC (inter process communication) which - in my opinion - should not be monitored in your case.

Comment: When i run the command `df -h` I get the following:
`none                       2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm`

Comment: 2G sounds to be not enough for general server usage. I have an Ubuntu 13.04 Server which has 20G by default. Does `ipcs -a` show any big shared memory allocation?

Comment: No. The biggest have ~16Mb
`ipcs -a
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status

0x78000c05 65538      zabbix_user     600        16777216   33
`

Comment: I'd check the installation requirements of the installed software. Does any of it mention required minimum shared memory? Does your configuration match the requirements? I'd enlist the installed software and calculate the minimum required shared memory from the documentations' data. If the requirements are higher than your configuration, raise it a little bit.

Comment: look like zabbix can detect these volumes in new kernels with snmpd, like in RHEL/Centos 7. for old systems it is not visible.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't wish to monitor the `Shared memory`on your system, you can easyly add it to the filter expression.

- For this go to "Administration"->"General"->"Regular expressions"
- Select the entry `Storage devices for SNMP discovery` entry
- Add the `Shared memory`entry to the list

At the same time you could also remove the various `/run/xxx` filesystems from discovery.

My current expression is:

`^(Physical memory|Virtual memory|Memory buffers|Cached memory|Swap space|Shared memory|/sys/fs/cgroup|/run/lock|/dev/shm|/run/user|/run/user/0|/run)$`

Comment: [https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-3311](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-3311)