# Excluding a certain file system from Zabbix regex based disk usage monitoring

Tags: regex, disk-space-utilization, zabbix, system-monitoring, exclude

I found [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/769697/467580) describing how to exclude a shared memory mount from regex based disk usage monitoring in Zabbix.

Is there any way to exclude a certain file system (CIFS in this case)... for example based on mount point?

Br,

Harri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question talks both about filesystem types and mountpoints (mentioning CIFS and "based on mount point"). It seems that the intent is to exclude based on mountpoint in the end.

Filesystems can be excluded from monitoring same way as described in the answer you linked to, you just have to filter by the LLD macro `{#FSNAME}`.

To do so, create a new [global regexp](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/regular_expressions#global_regular_expressions) (name is up to you) with the "Character string not included" expression of the filesystem you want to exclude. Then add an [LLD filter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#filter) on the `{#FSNAME}` macro using this global regexp (reference it by name, prefixed with `@`).

Comment: I don't want to exclude all the CIFS mounts if that's what you suggested. I just want to exclude a single CIFS mount provided by 2nd party file server.

Comment: Right, I just clarified based on the fact that you had mentioned the filesystem type. The `{#FSNAME}` LLD macro will allow to filter by names (mountpoints).

Comment: Great! Can you specify which regex should be changed and how if I want to exclude this kind of mount `//2ndpartyserver/shares/myshare on /mnt/mymountpoint type cifs (rw,mand)`?

Comment: Added details in the answer.